# Understanding the IdentityServer and API communication

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

From what I have researched, then it's best practice to seperate the API and IdentityServer into 2 projects (also 2 domains-i.e.: https://api.mywebsite.com and https://identity.mywebsite.com), so I did that.

In my IdentityServer/AuthenticationController.cs @ login-method it is currently making a JWT-token with a list of Claims(role(s), name, Jti(idk what that is), email, etc, that it puts into the JwtSecurityToken.

How does i.e. [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] in my WebAPI/ProductController.cs communicate with my IdentityServer and then authorizing it. Is it in "AddAuthentication(...);" in Program.cs services? Or in AddJwtBearer(...)? Or specifically in ValidIssuer?

Where is the connection between API(i.e. https://api.mywebsite.com) and IdentityServer(https://identityserver.mywebsite.com)?

My IdentityServer-project Program.cs:

```
...
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer().AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddClientStore<InMemoryClientStore>().AddResourceStore<InMemoryResourcesStore>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        
        ValidAudiences = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidAudiences").Get<string[]>(),
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
    };
}); 
...
```

My API-project Program.cs:

```
...
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

        ValidAudiences = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidAudiences").Get<string[]>(),
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
    };
});
...
```

Also, are my both codeblocks well-written when it comes to IdentityServer and API authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddJwtBearer in the API is in charge of taking the incoming access token and converting it to a "ClaimsPrincipal" user. Then that user is passed with all its claim to the authorization handler that will determine if the user is allowed to pass or not.

For example the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] attribute will check the role claims in the user if it contains the Admin role claim or not.

Usually you don't need to specify the IssuerSigningKey in AddJwtBearer and instead let AddJwtBearer to automatically retrieve it from IdentityServer directly at startup. (just remove IssuerSigningKey). You typically add IssuerSigningKey if the API can't talk to IdentityServer.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: That makes sense! If I remove the IssuerSigningKey from the Program.cs, do I need to remove it as well in my AuthenticationController at Login-method (JwtSecurityToken with signingCredentials).  `JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"], audience: configuration["JWT:ValidAudiences"], expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),claims: authClaims, signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));`

Comment: You should not need to do any JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken().... anywhere... the IdentityServer does that for you.

Comment: When you login, you challenge the user in the client application and the user is automatically redirected to IdentityServer and then it will pass the tokens back to the client.

Comment: When I remove the whole JwtSecurityToken token, then I have nothing in the `return Ok(token + expire date);`, then I can't get the token to print out the token in my PostMan to test it in my API calls, what do I do then

Comment: Upon testing several times, removing JwtSecurityToken from the system, it will not work and you get StatusCode 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own tokens? Its hard to tell what you are doing with so little  code.  If you use IdentityServer, it will issue the tokens automatically for you and you should not need to write any JwtSecurityToken code. you also in the client, use the AddOpenIDConnect handler to do the handling of OpenIDConnect in the client.  Are you using that?

Comment: I'm using a simple API where IdentityServer and AspNetIdentity are being used. I have created my own API Controller inside IdentityServer to just Login and Register. The return of Login is Ok(token) and the person/client can see a Json format with the JWT inside it.

Comment: feel free to post new questions on StackOverflow if you have more specific questions. :-)